# auto start generated product bundles

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, tycho, eclipse-pde, tycho-surefire-plugin

I have an equinox server application which I build, using PDE product configuration.
Since it is a server application, I would like to start ALL bundles right away.
The launch configuration provides the option "Default Auto-Start:".
I did not find any similar configuration for the `config.ini`.

I have x different product configurations for our customers.
Each customer has his own feature, depending on the main software feature.
Each product configuration is based on the customer feature, actually a very simple clean way. But since I want to start all the bundles I have to add all the bundles with `autoStart="true"` to the product configuration.

This is especially bad when I add or remove a bundle from the software. Having to update all configurations.

Any solution? Did I miss a configuration property?

**EDIT**: 
Maybe there is a solutions with tycho which will set all bundles to true in:
**configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info**

For the surefire tests there is:

```
<defaultStartLevel>
    <level>6</level>
    <autoStart>true</autoStart>
</defaultStartLevel>
```

Comment: Is this a xxx.product file you are using?

Comment: yes, an eclipse product file

Answer (score 1):

In a .product file you can specify start levels on the 'Start Levels' section of the 'Configuration' tab using the .product file editor.

The actual entries in the .product file look like:

```xml
<configurations>
  <plugin id="plugin.id" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
</configurations>
```

Comment: I added more information describing the problem. Searching for a configuration which starts ALL bundles automatically, without having to declare each with autoStart="true". Something similar as in the launch configuration.

Comment: There is a work around described here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/38599/